# I'm having access issues when using the class I created

Tags: flutter, dart

Like this I have a code:

```
final Storage storage = Storage();
// ....

  onPressed: () async {
    final results = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      type: FileType.image,
      allowMultiple: false,
      allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', "jpeg"],
    );
    if (results == null) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text("Resim seçmediniz."),
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 36, 36, 36),
        ),
      );
      return null;
    }
    final path = results.files.single.path!;
    final fileName = results.files.single.name;

    Storage.uploadFile(path, fileName);
  },
```

Also I have `storage_services.dart`:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';

class Storage {
  final FirebaseStorage _storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;

  Future<void> uploadFile(String filePath, String fileName) async {
    File file = File(filePath);
    try {
      await _storage.ref("$fileName").putFile(file);
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

My codes were like this. I am getting an error. Error:

[image]

```
Instance member 'uploadFile' can't be accessed using static access.dartstatic_access_to_instance_member
```

I'm trying to code by looking at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sM-WMcX66FI

How can I solve the problem? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `Storage.uploadFile` should be `storage.uploadFile`. Dart is case-sensitive

Comment: I'm immersed. Thank you.